# Why casting the object is redundant

Tags: java, android, interface

I have two constructors for an expandable list as shown below, and i have one interface shown below as well. now i want to use the same expandlist adapter for 
two different activities that's why i created two constructors. but the problem is when initialise the constructors, as you see in the 1st constructor when i
initilaise the interface object to the 2nd parameter in the constructor, i receive "Redundant casting" while in the 2nd constructor it is mandatory to initialise
the interface object to the 2nd parameter which the activity that should implement that interface

please explain why the casting in the 1st constructor is rundant while its manadory in the 2nd one?

**update**

```
both activities extends AppCompatActivity
```

***code**:

```
public MyExpandableList(Context ctx, ActMain actMain, ArrayList<Group> groupList) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
    this.mGroupList = groupList;
    this.mBTUtils = new BTUtils(ctx);
    this.mDevDetailsObserver =  (IDeviceDetailsPasser) actMain;//redundant casting, which is not necessary
}

public MyExpandableList(Context ctx, ActConnect actConnect, ArrayList<Group> groupList) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
    this.mGroupList = groupList;
    this.mBTUtils = new BTUtils(ctx);
    this.mDevDetailsObserver = (IDeviceDetailsPasser) actConnect;//manadory casting

}

//interface
public interface IDeviceDetailsPasser {
public void onDevicedetailsChosen(Header header, Details details, int groupPos);
```

}

Comment: How are you defining the `ActMain` and `ActConnect` classes?

Comment: @LetsamrIt  seems like `ActMain` implements `IDeviceDetailsPasser`

Comment: @MikeM. please the update..it that want want to know??

Comment: Provide the definition of `ActMain` and `ActConnect ` and also how 'mDevDetailsObserver ' is declared ?

Comment: @MikeM. i think i got from Rahul Tiwari's comment, my 1st activity implements IDeviceDetailsPasser..and i think that you would have said as well

Comment: @LetsamrIt You got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like `ActMain` already implements `IDeviceDetailsPasser`, that's why redundant casting.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case, your `actMain` implements `IDeviceDetailsPasser`, so casting is redundant, while your `actConnect` does not implement `IDeviceDetailsPasser`, so casting is mandatory.

**EDIT**:
to handle ClassCastException, use `try/catch`

```
    try {
        mDevDetailsObserver = (IDeviceDetailsPasser) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement IDeviceDetailsPasser");
    }
```

Comment: *"so casting is mandatory."* and likely to fail with a `ClassCastException`. But who knows.